# Payumoney Webhook not working

Tags: php, payumoney

Payumoney Webhook not working.

What payumoney told that:

> Your webhook should acknowledge that it received data with a 200 OK response. Any response outside of the 200 range will be treated as failure to send the data.

I'm giving complete url and page is giving 200 OK response.

index.php file contains

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
?>
```

every time they popup error "Some error occurred. Please try again."

Comment: make sure your header() call actually succeeds and there isn't a "headers already sent" problem.

Comment: @MarcB header is working fine no errors

Comment: @ViratPateldid you get the error fixed?

Comment: yes. i solve the issue

Comment: How! Please answer your question yourself if you fixed it it will help others too.

Comment: What i noticed here is those idiots say they are posting to the URL but actually they ping the server with a GET request, then i wrote a GET route also which just throws  200 OK response which their web hook said 403 i wonder why!. And then i got connection refused error after few minutes without changing anything.